# anchor to div don't work in area shape

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, shapes, area

I have map image area such as:

```
 <area shape="circle" coords="60,59,20"  href="#div1" item="list1">
```

And I use following function to show/hide my div:

```
<!-- jQuery Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[item]').click(function(){
    var item=$(this).attr('item');
    $(".display").hide();
    $("#"+item).show();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

And in body I have

```
<div id="list1" style="display:none;">Test</div>
```

I click on the area map and the div shows correctly, but the anchor to the div does not work.
Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `a` element with attribute `name="div1"` before your div:

```
<a name="div1"></a>
<div id="list1" style="display:none;">Test</div>
```

This is [how anchors works](http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html), example:

```
<a href="#anyword">Jump to any place</a>
...
<a name="anyword">Jump to this place</a>
```